# How to display previous and next buttons on sides of images with variable width with css?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a **photo gallery** (using javascript), and I want to display **previous and next buttons** on the current photo. Since we are talking about a photo gallery, the width of the currently displayed photo won't always be the same. I want the buttons to be over (in front of) the photo. What is the best way to do that with css?

**The images have variable widths!!** ex. Some will be in landscape mode, others in portrait

I have tried to display the buttons with `<a>` element, and the `<img>` between them. I decreased the margins of the buttons so they would overlap the image.

html part:

```
<div class="col-md-12 cont">
   <a role="button" data-slide="prev" class="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" style=""></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <img id="big-one" src="img.jpg" width="auto" height="550px" style="max-width: 100%;"/>
   <a role="button" data-slide="next" class="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"style=""></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>             
</div>
```

css part:

```
.cont{
   text-align:center;
}
.prev{
   cursor:pointer;
   margin-right:-24px;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}
.next{
   cursor:pointer;
   margin-left:-24px;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   height: 100%;
   background-color:blueviolet; //only for testing
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   height: 100%;
   background-color:blueviolet; //only for testing
}
.sr-only {
   position: absolute;
   width: 1px;
   height: 1px;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
   white-space: nowrap;
   border: 0;
}
```

Contrary to my expectations, the previous button is behind the current image. And the image doesn't keep its vertical position. What do I have to fix in the good to get what I want?

Comment: Can I use javascript?

Comment: @xmastertje I prefer css for this

Comment: check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

Comment: @xmastertje the link does not help, my images have different widths, they are not equally wide

Comment: Do you want to fix that?

Comment: I can't. Some photos will be in portrait mode, some will be landscape. It has to be that way

Comment: So you want something like [this?](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Comment: No, in that link the images have equal width

Comment: You have to wrap the images and links **tightly** in a div. I suspect your images are smaller that the columns you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a wrapper around the image and prev/next elements can let you both center and control where the prev/next buttons are placed on the images.

If we make a wrapper around the image that is only as wide as the image, then set the prev/next buttons to absolute positioning according to that wrapper, they will always appear over the image no matter the dimensions of the image.

Also not sure what the intent with the two spans inside the `<a>` elements are for.  I think one can be ommited, like below.  The `<a>`s need widths and heights, but you can change them to whatever you'd like.  Some of the CSS can be combined as well, but I did not do that here.

```css
.cont{
   display: flex;
}
.image-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.prev,
.next {
   cursor:pointer;
  background-color:blueviolet;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
    height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
   z-index: 1;
}
.prev {
  left: 0;
}
.next{
  right: 0;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
#big-one {
  display: block;
}
.sr-only {
   position: absolute;
   width: 1px;
   height: 1px;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
   white-space: nowrap;
   border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 cont">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
   <a role="button" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev-icon prev"><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      
   </a>
   <img id="big-one" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="auto" height="550px" style="max-width: 100%;"/>
   <a role="button" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next-icon next"><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      
   </a>  
  </div>
</div>
```